# Do we need Unity questions?

Tags: discussion

First of all I've nothing to Unity, I use Unity by my own. But do Stack Overflow need Unity questions? Are there not better on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) or the [forum of Unity](http://forum.unity3d.com/)? Aren't this no beter platform to ask their questions?